# How should I add multiple controls to a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Disclaimer, I'm rather new to WPF.

Currently, whenever I place another control onto the Designer, all other controls are ***completely erased*** from the XAML code. Consequently, I'm completely unable to do anything.

Should I be making a separate XAML file for each control? Or is there something weird going on otherwise?

For reference, here is my current XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Lively.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lively"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Lively" Height="450" Width="662" Foreground="Black" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Cursor="Arrow" MouseDown="DragWindow">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleY="2"/>
                    <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="40.601" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.033"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF360606" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0F0202"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0D0101" Offset="0.248"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FE170202"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0B0101" Offset="0.211"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF080808" Offset="0.256"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2E0606" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0E0707" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF010000" Offset="0.274"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Window.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.207"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.007"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.OpacityMask>
    <Image x:Name="Logo" Source="src/Assets/Core/Lively_32x32.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="619,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.467,0.5" Stretch="None" ToolTip="Just the logo :)"/>
</Window>
```

To compound an example, if I drop a label on the Designer, the entire `<Image>` tag will be deleted as if it never existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `Window` element can contain a single element. but you can make it a container like Grid or any other container element that can have other elements as child. and inside that you can add as many elements as you want

```
<Window x:Class="GPRS_Simulator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GPRS_Simulator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="GPRS SIMULATOR" Height="393" Width="708.5" Loaded="winloaded" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Label .... your label parameters/>
        <ComboBox .... your comboBox parameters/>
        <Button .... your button parameters/>
        ... other elements
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So inplace of your

`<Image x:Name="Logo" Source=.../>`

You should use a container element like the Grid I used in the above to contain multiple elements.

eg.

```
<Grid>
   <Image x:Name="Logo" Source=.../>
   <Button x:Name= ...../>
   <other elements you want to add ... ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this in a minute. One question though...is it a good practice? Is it possible to use multiple files for high-density windows? Or should I remain with a Grid? This is only a splash screen I'm making so it'll be fine here, but I'm curious for the future.

Comment: @wellinthatcase: honestly, my experience has been that it is better to learn to write the XAML directly. I wish the Designer worked better, but I find it annoying to use, and it can be hard to express layout scenarios with the Designer that are straightforward to just write as XAML. Whether you use the Designer or not, you certainly can modularize your XAML, using `UserControl`, templates, and separate resource dictionary files. That's independent of how you author the XAML itself.